# Dynamically define object/property name in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm working with a very large model which has hundreds of properties on it.

One of those properties is defined as such:

```
model.itemDescription1Code
model.itemDescription2Code
model.itemDescription3Code
model.itemDescription4Code
```

All the way up to 18.

I want to scroll through just these 18 different properties on the model, is there some way I can have something like this:

```
for(var i = 1; i < 18; i ++) {
    var code = model.'itemDescription' + i + 'code';
}
```

Obviously what I have above will not work at all, but I'm wondering if there's a way I can construct the property name in my for loop and then reference it off that model with the dynamically constructed name.

Comment: you should use [] instead of . like model['itemDescription' + i + 'code']

Comment: also [Bracket notation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the dynamic key as array index:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 18; i ++) {
    var code = model['itemDescription' + i + 'code'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wont say the answer above me is wrong, but it will be more coeectly and less hardcoded to use foreach..
For (i in model) 
{
//use what ever you want on the item..
}

Comment: I in something is acting like foreach...even in complexabilty..its a bad idea when not using it in the right places...this array contains objects of objects which may or maynot be in sequencial order..itemDescription3 and itemDescription5 without 4.. So 4 will throw an error if using hardcoded values.